# Objective C - Return 2D string array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, string, text

I am making a function that should return a 2d array of words. Once in english and once in slovak. These words are stored in TXT file. I am understanding the txt and it's working, however the compiler seems to have a problem with returning NSString 2d array. Can you please have a look at it?

This is the function last but one line giving error: 
Incompatible pointer types returning 'NSString *__strong[[array count]][2]' from a function with result type 'NSString'

```
- (NSString*) getWordArray
{
    NSArray *array = [self getTxtArray];
    NSString *str[[array count]] [2];
    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
    {
        NSArray *translation = [array[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        str[i][0] = [translation objectAtIndex:0];
        str[i][1] = [translation objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    return str;
}
```

These functions works fine. Just to show you in case you're interested because they're used in the problematic one

```
- (NSString*) getTxt
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];
    if (filePath)
    {
        NSString *contentOfFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        return contentOfFile;
    }
    return @"";
}

- (NSArray*) getTxtArray
{
    NSArray* array = [[self getTxt] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `NSMutableArray` for your 2D array of strings. Your `getWordArray` method then look like this:

```
- (NSArray *)getWordArray
{
    NSArray *array = [self getTxtArray];
    NSMutableArray *strArray = [NSMutableArray array]; // This is your 2D array
    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
    {
        NSArray *translation = [array[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        // translation is assumed to be an array with two elements
        [strArray addObject:translation];
    }
    return strArray;
}
```

This works because a 2D array is an array of arrays and since `componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an array, we can stuff each of these into a container array.